# Using the same trigger name and the same variable name in Angular Animations

Tags: angular, ionic4, angular-animations, ionicons

I have a bunch of arrow-down icons, and i need to rotate then 180 degress and im using the Angular Animations to do this

```
  <ion-icon
    name="ios-arrow-down"
    (click)="rotateArrow()"
    [@arrowRotation]="state"></ion-icon>
```

I have 5 of these icons using the same @arrowRotatioon trigger and the same variable "state" and in the function i call this

```
  rotateArrow() {
this.state = this.state === 'default' ? 'rotated' : 'default';}
```

it works but when i click in one icon it rotates all the 5 icons, and i dont want to create 5 different variables to each trigger or 5 different trigger name to do the same thing, anyone knows a way to rotate just one arrow when clicked ?